# Where to define arrayList type variable as static in java web application?

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, arraylist, web-config

How and where to define a variable which is common for all users who access the JSF web application.

As for as I know when application is accessed from different browsers, Application server creates single instance of the web application for each user. So each user maintains their own copy of instance variables of the servlets.

Having said that, My requirement is, i have to have a variable which is used by all users to read, delete and update it's content and variable data type is arraylist.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: I think as you said the only way is to use database. But i had a doubt like, Can i define variable as context param in web.xml and use it as global variable? Could i achieve in that way? Please share your thought.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what `@ApplicationScoped` exists for. An application scoped bean will only exist once and will be the same for all users.

In case you are not using JSF 2, the alternative would be `@Singleton`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/) for further information regarding the scopes.

Comment: Note that the answer currently linked behind your "See this" text has completely nothing to do with EJB's `@Singleton` annotation as mentioned in your answer. Just saying to avoid confusion by OP (and probably yourself). A better link is perhaps this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope/ The EJB's `@Singleton` is at least inappropriate for the purpose of a pure application wide data container.

Comment: @BalusC I have actually never used `@Singleton`, but I think it's part of CDI, not limited to EJBs? And since `@Singleton` resources will only be created once and always be the same when injected, it's basically the same like an `@ApplicationScoped` bean, isn't it? But I agree, the link is really misleading, I replace it.

Comment: Have you looked at package name of `@Singleton`? The CDI equivalent is also just called `@ApplicationScoped`.

Comment: @BalusC `javax.inject.Singleton` How the hell can you answer so *instantly*?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Servlet Context](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html), this will be available for entire application